# Escape user input for use in JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I am building a highlight feature for search results on my website and need to escape the user's input so that I could highlight the matching string within the original text.

**The function**

```
function sanitize_for_regex(s){
    var escaped = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i){
        switch(s[i]){
            case '{':
            case '}':
            case '[':
            case ']':
            case '-':
            case '/':
            case '\\':
            case '(':
            case ')':
            case '*':
            case '+':
            case '?':
            case '.':
            case '^':
            case '$':
            case '|':
                escaped+= '\\';
            default:
                escaped+= s[i];
        }
    }
    return escaped;
}
```

**How it's used**

```
var input_from_user = 'Hey + wi$ll th<is \'" { tex|t / \\ mess w?>ith you?';

var highlighted_text = original_text.replace(new RegExp('('+sanitize_for_regex(input_from_user)+')', 'gi'), '<span style="background-color:#FBFB73;">$1</span>');
```

My test cases show that it's working quite well but I would like to get some feedback from other professionals.

Does this function look like it will escape all injection "attempts"? (I quoted attempts because the user is usually not aware of attempting to break anything)

Could the performance be improved?

Comment: Why not look at some prior work? This is what Google uses, and they're notoriously keen on performance... http://stackoverflow.com/a/18151038/3757232

Comment: @JaredSmith I've actually seen that answer. Unfortunately I am not a regex expert and as a rule-of-thumb you should never blindly use code which you do not understand. The [accepted answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153702/33623) and comments clearly define what it's doing and why. If you could enlighten me as to why the Google one is different then I would consider using it. Feel free to add it as an answer, I will, at minimum, upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Its probably not worthy of an answer: all the first replace is doing is taking the list of regex special characters and adding a double backslash in front of any found in the string (the capturing group match is assigned to the automatic variable `$1`. There are comments on the answer that explain the second replace. And that's a good rule of thumb, but time spent deciphering regexes is the price you pay for getting good at them.

Comment: @JaredSmith I think I already understood most of that so I should have phrased my question in this way "Why does the Google solution escape more characters than the answer provided by 200_success?" especially considering 200_success's explanation about the square brackets and dashes? In regards to optimization and ignoring the `replace(/\x08/g, '\\x08')` section, wouldn't the additional and potentially unnecessary regex matching cause a decrease in the performance which Google is so keen on achieving?

Comment: Because a general purpose solution is better (more battle-tested) than a bunch of one-off ad hoc ones. Doing a one-off that only escapes the characters you're interested in for a particular use-case is the kind of thing you only do once profiling has shown the general purpose solution to be too slow.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not a fan of "sanitizing" data.  There isn't a clear definition of what "sanitizing" means, other than that it takes untrustworthy input and somehow makes it valid.  It might entail discarding the invalid parts of the input — which is not what you are doing here.  *Escaping* is a clearer term to describe what you are doing.

Repeated string concatenation is considered poor practice for performance.  Since JavaScript strings are immutable, it would be better to devise a solution that constructs the string "all at once".

The [documentation on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) suggests the following solution for escaping a regular expression:

> Escaping user input to be treated as a literal string within a regular
>   expression can be accomplished by simple replacement:
>
> ```
> function escapeRegExp(string){
>   return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
> }
> ```

I strongly recommend replacing your custom solution with the standard recipe (including a citation).

Comment: Oh wow, this is really excellent. I've come across other solutions like this on StackOverflow but for some reason I could not get it to work with my code; probably due to my regex inexperience. My code used to be a larger mess until I narrowed my vision for what I actually need it to accomplish. This works as a drop-in replacement for my function and I feel silly for not seeing the Mozilla docs sooner. Thanks a million!

Comment: I think you forgot to add `-`(hyphen) in  the character class. When used in character class, this need to escape or it may select range.

Comment: @Tushar But character classes are simply not possible if the square brackets are already escaped.

Comment: Aah. True. Didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple options as far as escaping goes:

1. You can use a regular expression that matches any character that needs escaped and replaces it with `"\\&$"`, which is "A backslash, followed by whatever character matched.":

   ```
   // The inside regexp just replaces every character with a leading backslash for readability.
   // It can be optimized out just fine.

   var pattern = RegExp("[" + "{}[]-/\\()*+?.%$|".replace(RegExp(".", "g"), "\\$&") + "]", "g");

   function sanitize_for_regex(val) {
       return val.replace(pattern, "\\$&");
   }
   ```
2. You can keep your current code somewhat as-is (but it's relatively inefficient), but checking a string rather than a bunch of `case`:

   ```
   function sanitize_for_regex(s) {
       var escaped;
       for(var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i){
           if("{}[]-/\\()*+?.%$|".indexOf(s[i]) !== -1) {
               escaped += "\\";
           }
           escaped += s[i];
       }
       return escaped;
   }
   ```

As for what needs to be escaped, you're probably matching far more than you need to -- many of those symbols only have meaning when paired with other symbols that you're already escaping, thus:

- It's not neccessary to escape `-` or `^`, because you're already escaping `[` and `]` and thus -- unless you're using the input *inside* of that part of a pattern, they'll never be treated as special characters.
- It's technically not necessary to escape `]`, because the `[` that would begin that part of the pattern is already escaped.
- If you're only using the output inside of a pattern (as opposed to inside of a replacement), I believe the only things that really need escaping are the backslash (`\`), wildcards and the start of character classes (`.` and `[`), quantifiers (`?`, `+`, `*` and `{`), parenthesis (`(` and `)`) and branching expressions (`|`).
- So, in short, the list of characters to escape are `()[.?+*{|`.

This may vary a bit depending on your usage though.

Comment: Great suggestions, I'm really learning quite a bit! I just facepalmed pretty hard because I did not think of the string and `indexOf()` approach. Since this is targeted for use upon hitting a key and the search terms should never exceed more than 10 characters I think it will be safe to use the `indexOf()` approach. Even with 1,000 chars in the search term there is no slow down. Thanks!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The regex approach is likely faster (it's not constructing a string one character at a time), but I listed the other to show one that was closer to your original approach.

Comment: I decided to construct the string outside of the `for(){}` loop's scope and assign it to a variable named `escape_chars`. My `for(){}` loop looks like this on the inside `escaped_val+= (escape_chars.indexOf(s[i]) !== -1 ? '\\' : '')+s[i];` I am choosing to avoid regex because I cannot read it very well so readable code trumps uber-optimization in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a big performance deal, yet you could use a "hashset" instead of going through the cases:

```
var dispatch = {
    '{':  true,
    '}':  true,
    '[':  true,
    ']':  true,
    '-':  true,
    '/':  true,
    '\\': true,
    '(':  true,
    ')':  true,
    '*':  true,
    '+':  true,
    '?':  true,
    '.':  true,
    '^':  true,
    '$':  true,
    '|':  true
};

function sanitize_for_regex2(val) {
    var escaped = "";

    for (var i = 0; i !== val.length; ++i) {
        if (dispatch[val[i]]) {
            escaped += "\\";
        }

        escaped += val[i];
    }

    return escaped;
}

alert(sanitize_for_regex2("{yeah}"));
alert(sanitize_for_regex("{yeah}"));
```

Comment: This will certainly clean up my function but I hesitate to put function-specific variables outside of the function's scope. Do you think to would be a huge penalty to declare the hash every time the function is called? Any ideas as to whether or not I've considered all possible regex injection points?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The answer to your 1st question: it would seem the hash will be created every time the function is called. Maybe closures may help. 2nd one: I really don't know (I am *not a professional* JavaScript developer). :-(

Comment: I appreciate the insight, this definitely gives me something mull over, thanks!